# Cannot connect to pgadmin runtime developer server

Tags: pgadmin-4, apache-age

I am trying to follow the README for building the pgadmin runtime from https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/tree/master. As instructed, I activate my python virtual environment, then go into the runtime directory and run the following command:

`sudo node_modules/nw/nwjs/nwjs.app/Contents/MacOS/nwjs .`

It then tries to contact the server but I get an error that says:

*The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:*

I have followed the instructions step-by-step but the server is unable to be contacted. I tried checking whether the port being contacted is already in use, but the port is free.

Answer (score 0):

check if the server configuration is correct or not and ensure the server is accessible, still, if it does not work try clearing the cache and restart the server and pg admin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the server is running. You have to run the server before running the following command.

```
sudo node_modules/nw/nwjs/nwjs.app/Contents/MacOS/nwjs
```

You have to make sure that pgadmin configuration matches the one that you are using to access the server.

So, first check the server status and then check the pgadmin configurations.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the directory `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin from your system.`
- Access the terminal and execute the file `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\[version]\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py` using Python

To ensure proper functioning, launch the "pgAdmin 4" application from the Windows menu by right-clicking and selecting "Run as administrator."